# Installing private python wheel from a storage account

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I use a shared storage account across all our AML workspaces. I register this storage account on each workspace and use it to share data and libraries when targeting AML compute. To install a private python wheel, we currently have to download the package locally and use the Environment.add_private_pip_wheel to upload it and retrieve the remote url of the package. I would like to know if there’s a way to pass a reference to the package in the shared storage account instead of having to move it to the default workspace storage account.

I tried to pass the full blob url (e.g. https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mypackage.whl)  in the pip_packages dependency parameter to the TensorFlow estimator class but the experiment execution fails with a 404 error : The specified resource does not exist for url https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mypackage.whl

```py
from azureml.train.dnn import TensorFlow
from azureml.core.runconfig import MpiConfiguration

project_folder = "./myproject"

dependencies = ["https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mypackage.whl"]

script_params={
  "--data_dir":data_dir.as_mount(),
  "--output_dir":output_data.as_mount(),
  "--do_train":"True",
  "--do_eval":"False",
  "--do_predict":"False",
}

mpiConfig = MpiConfiguration()
mpiConfig.process_count_per_node = 1
estimator= TensorFlow(source_directory=project_folder,
                      compute_target=compute_target,
                      script_params=script_params,
                      entry_script='./train_classifier.py',
                      node_count=1,
                      distributed_training=mpiConfig,
                      pip_packages=dependencies,
                      framework_version='1.13',
                      use_gpu=True)
```

Since the storage account has been registered in the workspace, I expect to be able to install the private package directly (using the code above) from the shared storage account into AML compute without having to download it locally and then calling Environment.add_private_pip_wheel function.

Instead, I get the following error and the experiment fails:

(from -r /azureml-environment-setup/condaenv.kc80np3o.requirements.txt (line 1)) because of HTTP error 404 Client Error: The specified resource does not exist. for url: https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mypackage.whl ...

CondaValueError: pip returned an error

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make your storage account public readable, you could create a [SAS URL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/10/12/easily-create-a-sas-to-download-a-file-from-azure-storage-using-azure-storage-explorer/) for your whl package, and then pass that to pip dependencies. Then the service should be able to access the package.

Comment: I understand that's an option, but I was wondering why the azureml SDK can't use the account credentials that I passed while registering the account/container as a datastore in the workspace.